# Want resolution 1600x900 for Lenovo G570

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, high-resolution

I am using Lenovo G570 laptop with 15.6 Inch of screen. It's maximum resolution is 1366x768 now i want to use it with my monitor of 20 Inch Wide SAMSUNG SyncMaster S20B300. I used VGA cable for it and i got what i want but my laptop provide maximum resolution 1366x768 and monitor expect 1600x900 so in monitor it looks like blured.

So what i want is resolution from 1366x768 to 1600x900.

I googled some references but failed to get proper solution. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Have you try to set monitor as extension to main screen? Not copy

Comment: @RomeoNinov I tried it after your suggestion but in this case monitor screen become unresponsive. It shows only desktop wallppaer, no icon no other application that I open in laptop.

Comment: Will applications drag across onto your second screen?

Comment: @JamieWilletts unfortunately no, it shows only desktop wallpaper and taskbar, not even cursor.

Comment: Try setting the monitor as your primary display. To do this, go on control panel, display, settings and then identify and try to move them so they are as you require.

Comment: @JamieWilletts in that case my desktop gone off :(

Comment: @JamieWilletts your last suggestion works. Please write it as answer and i will accept it as the best answer.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the monitor as the primary display, 'Control Panel > Display > Settings > Identify' and move the displays around as you require.

Comment: It is solved, but for future reference: make sure computer recognizes the external screen, at least by supported resolutions, if not by model and make. If it can't, updating the external display driver is in order.